# Controlling Location of PHP Echo Statement

Tags: php, html, css, sql, echo

I've recently created a PHP script for my website.  It allows users to register and log in for membership purposes only.  If the user logs in successfully, the script redirects them to a members landing page, and if the login fails, the script is directed to

```
echo "<p class='yellowclass'>Login failed</p>";
```

.yellowclass is set as yellow since my page's background is black, but I've run into an issue.  I don't want `Login failed` to appear at the top of my page, I want it to appear somewhere else.  How would I go about controlling where on the page that echo statement appears?

Comment: Variables are free, use as many as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the position of the html tag through CSS by increasing the elements margin or if the elements is in absolute position, use the top,left,right,bottom css properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: `$error = "Login failed!";`

Then, later in the page, use this:

```
if( $error) echo "<div class=\"yellowclass\">".$error."</div>";
```

This will make the error message appear wherever you want.